# Update credentials after social login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I let my users login using different social logins like github and facebook.

My problem is that when they have created different types of entities in the system I need to assign them permissions to the new entities.

I have used claims for this doing something like this:

1. Create a new identity/principal with updated claims
2. Logout the current authentication scheme
3. Login using CookieAuthentication

Code:

```
var currentScheme = User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod);
var principal = await _principalService.CreateAppPrincipal(User.GetUserId());
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(currentScheme.Value);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

That have worked fine until I updated to asp.net core 2.1.

Now I get the following error:

> The authentication handler registered for scheme 'Facebook' is 'FacebookHandler' which cannot be used for SignOutAsync. The registered sign-out schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, Cookies.'

Current claims (before the update):

[image]

Why is that? Why can't I logout users when they have used a social login?

Comment: I expect that pre-2.1, `SignOutAsync` would have been a no-op in this case. Do you get the desired result if you just omit that call to `SignOutAsync`?

Comment: Good question, I'll check